# How to prevent my character controller from rotating on x or z axis?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using the in-built character controller and when I rotate my character towards an enemy target, my whole character object (I have a capsule) will also rotate so then my character ends up standing diagonal rather than vertical and if I look at the enemy target again, my character object will turn  completely horizontal.

```
public class LookAt : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform lookAtOpponent;

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 relativePosition = lookAtOpponent.position - transform.position;

        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePosition, Vector3.up);
        transform.rotation = rotation;
    }
}
```

I know rigidbody has contraints for each axis that you can tick but I can't figure this out with a controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way x,z don't change they are always set to 0

```
public class LookAt : MonoBehaviour
{
   public Transform lookAtOpponent;

   void Update()
   {
      Vector3 relativePosition = lookAtOpponent.position - transform.position;

      Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePosition, Vector3.up);
      transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0,rotation.eulerAngles.y,0);
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I was just looking at euler angles but didn't figure it out. This worked, thanks a lot